# Python 3.6, cx_oracle for 11g client on 64-bit windows

Tags: windows, oracle11g, 64-bit, cx-oracle, python-3.6

I am new to Python. The past couple of days I have tried to make cx_oracle work on 64-bit Windows 8.1 with Anaconda3 (3.6) and 11g Oracle client.

In the end I managed to make it work but it was quite cumbersome. Anaconda seems to be a widely used distribution, Windows a common OS, and cx_oracle windows binaries comes from python.org, so **can the following really be the way to do it?!?**

1. I was unable to use [Gholke's unofficial windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_oracle) becuse it must work for 11g client. I only found packages for 12c.
2. I could not make Visual C++ build tools 2015 (14.0) (not enough rep to make link ) work either, getting a long list of:
      `cx_Oracle.obj : error LNK2001 :unresolved external symbol OCIxxxxxx.`

   May be that I am missing something on the Oracle client side?

Finally, **what did work** was the official binaries https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle but not out of the box:

a.  Running cx_Oracle-5.3-11g.win-amd64-py3.6.exe as administrator I get a prompt: 
        `Python version 3.6-32 required, which is not found in the registry.`

b. Then I had to modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Python > PythonCore > 3.6`, changing the key value from `3.6` to `3.6-32`. Now the installer allows me to select a python version.

Looking back at the description it seems simple. However, it took a long time to find out and I don't find messing with regedit.exe that great.

I am hoping that someone out there has a better solution, 
thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the official binaries for the cx_Oracle 5.3 release: that is a known issue which has now been resolved.

I am also working on a way to distribute wheels instead of executable installers in order to avoid this long-term.

Comment: :Thank you taking the time to reply and pointing this out to me and . For some reason I have completely missed this discussion. Cheers